# Resourcify with Cancan, Devise and Rolify to limit resource access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, rolify

If I have CanCan setup with Devise and Rolify I should be able to use resourcify to limit access to varying resource types right?

For example.

Say I have an organization model which has a has_many relationship with model_a.

Users also have a singular organization that they belong to.Users have many instances of model_b as their association. I want to limit the scope of what Users can access in my entire organization to just the organization they belong to.

I should be able to setup something like this for an ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user   ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    org_id = user.organization.id unless user.organization.blank?

    if user.has_role?(:user)

     can :access, :home
     can [:read, :calendar], :model_a, :organization_id => user.organization.id if user.organization
    can :read, :model_b, :user_id => user.id
    can [:read, :update], :users, :id => user.id
  end
end
```

But my different resources keep popping up in different parts of my application unless I limit my queries to just this organization for the particular user. What gives? I thought rolify should do that automatically for me? Or should I use resourcify in my model_a and model_b class to set that up? If so, don't I need to also setup join tables for both of those models to my rolify table? Or can that be polymorphic?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. What do you mean by, "resources keep popping up in different parts of my application"? What should rolify do automatically? If you could add more relevant code and specify exactly the behavior you're seeing is, that'd be really helpful.

Comment: My apologies! I can add more code but I'm not sure what would be relevant. By the resources keep popping up, I mean that the models that I'm seeing should  be limited in scope to a particular organization from the :organization_id limit on Ability. From what I understand that means when I do a search on that particular model, shouldn't I only see results that my ability allows me to see? For example if I did Model.accessible_by(current_ability) shouldn't it be limited to what I can see within my organization from that limit on scope?

Comment: @BenNelson I suspect what you're looking for is [Multitenancy](https://github.com/influitive/apartment). Because, the concept of having authorization is to restrict what one can see based on their roles, not the group they belongs to. I mean, user of an organization should not be allowed to see other organization data as they are two separate clusters, so a user with role admin in an organization can update the organization detail while others(who are not admin but are in same organization) can not.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm surprised I haven't seen that Gem before! I'll try it out, if it fits my needs you can have the bounty.

Comment: @BenNelson : There are [plenty of gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy) for implementing multitenancy. You can checkout [this Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/388-multitenancy-with-scopes). [`acts_as_tenant`](https://github.com/ErwinM/acts_as_tenant) with a [blog post](http://www.rollcallapp.com/blog/2011/10/03/adding-multi-tenancy-to-your-rails-app-acts-as-tenant) but it's not been updated from a year. [Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) looks active. Checkout http://confreaks.com/videos/111-aac2009-writing-multi-tenant-applications-in-rails.

Comment: Here's another thought, about your question: did you try doing this: `can [:read, :calendar], :model_a => { :organization_id => user.organization.id } if user.organization` ??

Comment: Yeah I tried that, didn't seem to work for just general queries. I still ended up having to limit the scope manually in a where clause as well. It seemed strange to have to do that.